# SQL query: Edit Edit SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON; MySQL said: Documentation #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `RptGetBudgetVariance`;

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `RptGetBudgetVariance`(
    IN `v_CompanyID` VARCHAR(36), 
    IN `v_DivisionID` VARCHAR(36), 
    IN `v_DepartmentID` VARCHAR(36), 
    IN `v_AccountID` VARCHAR(36), 
    OUT `SWP_Ret_Value` TINYINT(2))
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_ErrorMessage VARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE v_FiscalStartDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period1EndDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period2EndDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period3EndDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period4EndDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period5EndDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period6EndDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period7EndDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period8EndDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period9EndDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period10EndDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period11EndDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period12EndDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period13EndDate datetime;
    DECLARE v_Period14EndDate datetime;
 

    
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
       BEGIN
          SET @SWV_Error = 1;
          GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @v_ErrorMessage_SQL = MESSAGE_TEXT;
       END;
       SET @SWV_Error = 0;
       SET @v_ErrorMessage_SQL = NULL;

    START TRANSACTION;

    -- get current Fiscal year and enddate for each period
    SELECT 
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.FiscalStartDate,'00:00:00'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period1Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"), 
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period2Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period3Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period4Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period5Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period6Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period7Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period8Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period9Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period10Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period11Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period12Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period13Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.Period14Date,'23:59:59'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")
    INTO 
        v_FiscalStartDate,
        v_Period1EndDate, 
        v_Period2EndDate,
        v_Period3EndDate,
        v_Period4EndDate,
        v_Period5EndDate,
        v_Period6EndDate,
        v_Period7EndDate,
        v_Period8EndDate,
        v_Period9EndDate,
        v_Period10EndDate,
        v_Period11EndDate,
        v_Period12EndDate,
        v_Period13EndDate,
        v_Period14EndDate
    FROM 
        companies c
    WHERE
    c.CompanyID = v_CompanyID AND
    c.DivisionID = v_DivisionID AND
    c.DepartmentID = v_DepartmentID;

     IF @SWV_Error <> 0 OR v_FiscalStartDate = '' THEN 
        SET v_ErrorMessage = 'Error getting the Current Fiscal Year';
        SET SWP_Ret_Value = 1;
    END IF;


    -- create temporary table
   /* CREATE Temporary Table v_detail(
        CompanyID VARCHAR(36),
        DivisionID VARCHAR(36),
        DepartmentID VARCHAR(36),
        Account VARCHAR(36),
        Period1Amount decimal(19,4),
        Period2Amount decimal(19,4),
        Period3Amount decimal(19,4),
        Period4Amount decimal(19,4),
        Period5Amount decimal(19,4),
        Period6Amount decimal(19,4),
        Period7Amount decimal(19,4),
        Period8Amount decimal(19,4),
        Period9Amount decimal(19,4),
        Period10Amount decimal(19,4),
        Period11Amount decimal(19,4),
        Period12Amount decimal(19,4),
        Period13Amount decimal(19,4),
        Period14Amount decimal(19,4)
    );
    */
    /* INSERT INTO v_detail(
        CompanyID ,
        DivisionID ,
        DepartmentID ,
        Account ,
        Period1Amount ,
        Period2Amount ,
        Period3Amount ,
        Period4Amount ,
        Period5Amount ,
        Period6Amount ,
        Period7Amount ,
        Period8Amount ,
        Period9Amount ,
        Period10Amount ,
        Period11Amount ,
        Period12Amount ,
        Period13Amount ,
        Period14Amount 
    ) */
        
        SELECT 
            td.CompanyID ,
            td.DivisionID ,
            td.DepartmentID,
            td.GLTransactionAccount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate >= v_FiscalStartDate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period1Enddate,IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0),0)) AS Period1Amount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate > v_Period1Enddate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period2Enddate,IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0),0)) AS Period2Amount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate > v_Period2Enddate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period3Enddate,IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0),0)) AS Period3Amount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate > v_Period3Enddate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period4Enddate,IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0),0))  AS Period4Amount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate > v_Period4Enddate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period5Enddate,IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0),0))  AS Period5Amount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate > v_Period5Enddate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period6Enddate, IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0),0)) AS Period6Amount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate > v_Period6Enddate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period7Enddate,IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0),0))  AS Period7Amount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate > v_Period7Enddate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period8Enddate,IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0),0))  AS Period8Amount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate > v_Period8Enddate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period9Enddate,IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0),0))  AS Period9Amount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate > v_Period9Enddate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period10Enddate,IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0),0))  AS Period10Amount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate > v_Period10Enddate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period11Enddate,IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0),0))  AS Period11Amount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate > v_Period11Enddate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period12Enddate,IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0),0))  AS Period12Amount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate > v_Period12Enddate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period13Enddate,IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0),0))  AS Period13Amount,
            SUM(IF(tr.GLTransactionDate > v_Period13Enddate AND tr.GLTransactionDate <= v_Period14Enddate,IFNULL(td.`GLCreditAmount`,0) - IFNULL(td.`GLDebitAmount`,0),0))  AS Period14Amount,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod1 AS Period1Budget,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod2 AS Period1Budget,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod3 AS Period1Budget,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod4 AS Period1Budget,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod5 AS Period1Budget,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod6 AS Period1Budget,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod7 AS Period1Budget,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod8 AS Period1Budget,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod9 AS Period1Budget,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod10 AS Period1Budget,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod11 AS Period1Budget,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod12 AS Period1Budget,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod13 AS Period1Budget,
            lcb.GLBudgetPeriod14 AS Period1Budget
        FROM 
            ledgertransactionsdetail td
        JOIN ledgertransactions tr ON
            td.CompanyID = tr.CompanyID AND td.DivisionID = tr.DivisionID AND td.DepartmentID = tr.DepartmentID AND td.GLTransactionNumber = tr.GLTransactionNumber
        JOIN ledgerchartofaccountsbudgets lcb ON
            lcb.CompanyID = tr.CompanyID AND lcb.DivisionID = tr.DivisionID AND lcb.DepartmentID = tr.DepartmentID AND lcb.GLAccountNumber = tr.GLTransactionNumber
        WHERE 
            td.CompanyID = v_CompanyID
            AND td.DivisionID = v_DivisionID
            AND td.DepartmentID = v_DepartmentID
            AND IF(ISNULL(v_AccountID),td.GLTransactionAccount = td.GLTransactionAccount,td.GLTransactionAccount = v_AccountID)
       GROUP BY
            td.CompanyID, td.DivisionID, td.DepartmentID, td.GLTransactionAccount;
       

      -- SELECT @v_ErrorMessage_SQL;
    
  
        IF @SWV_Error = 0 THEN 
            SET SWP_Ret_Value = 0;
            COMMIT;
        ELSE 
            ROLLBACK;
            SET SWP_Ret_Value = -1;
        END IF;



END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This code compiles fine and you are not setting foreign key checks in it so when exactly do you see this error?

Comment: @P.Salmon, I got the error at the point of calling the procedure